# Tomcat 7.0.16 not accepting password for webapp

Tags: tomcat, password, configuration

I am trying to set up Tomcat to password protect an entire webapp, but when I get the password prompt, it's not accepting the username/password I'm providing to it (just keeps prompting for the user/pass over and over), and if I cancel, I get a 401 error.

Any ideas why it's not working?  I'm currently using MemoryRealm, but tried UserDatabaseRealm too, replacing the appropriate MemoryRealm realm with the following in server.xml:

`<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase" />`

The logs just show `"GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 954`, and only after I cancel the authentication prompt.  Below are my configuration files (with comments removed for brevity)

server.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
          type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
          description="User database that can be updated and saved"
          factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
          pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>
  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm" />
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="/data/www/www.mysite.com/webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" resolveHosts="false"/>
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

tomcat-users.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="generic"/>
  <user username="myself" password="mypassword" roles="generic"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

web.xml (under /data/www/www.mysite.com/webapps/WEB-INF):

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.4">
  <display-name>/MySite-RPM_95_ca2f16f912c9dc4aab2a4fcb7c87cb9a1f1bbf04</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>MySite-RPM_95_ca2f16f912c9dc4aab2a4fcb7c87cb9a1f1bbf04</param-value>
  </context-param>
<!-- listeners, filters, servlets, welcome-file-list, error-pages, and jsp-config/taglibs snipped for brevity-->
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Entire Application</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>generic</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>My Realm</realm-name>
  </login-config>
</web-app>
```